# remove an element from a set and return the set

Tags: python, loops, set

I need to iterate over a copy of a set that doesn't contain a certain element. Until now I'm doing this:

```
for element in myset:
    if element != myelement:
       ...
```

But I want something like this, in one line:

```
for element in myset.copy().remove(myelement):
    ...
```

Obviously this doesn't work because the `remove` method returns None.

Comment: Are you looking for `difference()`? Maybe like `set([1,2,3]).difference(set([3]))`

Comment: Would you consider editing the question title? "remove an element from a set and return the set" implies that you want to mutate the original set - whereas on reading the question itself, you make it clear that you don't (you want a copy with an element removed).

Comment: I think the title is apt, because OP expected to be able to use a method on the set that would allow them to chain.

Comment: @Grismar Totally, but reading the title made me expect that OP was looking for the chaining equivalent of `myset.remove(myelement)` rather than of `myset.copy().remove(myelement)`. Could well be that my brain's parser is in the minority though!

Comment: No, I think you're right - but the title is supposed to draw in people with the same problem, and as OP didn't appear to be aware of what's available, I think it's right. See my answer for where I took that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the set difference operator.

```
for element in myset - {myelement}:
    ...
```

This creates a new set containing the elements of `myset` that aren't in `{myelement}` (namely, `myelement` itself).

Comment: This is cool, didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you're after?

```
myset = {1, 2, 3, 4}

for element in myset - {3}:
    print(element)
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
```

You're correct that `remove()` returns `None` upon success instead of the resulting set, it operates in-place without supporting chaining. However, an infix operator like `-` will be evaluated and return the result. In a sense, you can see `set1 - set2` as `-(set1, set2)`, that does return the result or `set1.-(set2)` if you prefer.

In fact, that method exists:

```
myset = {1, 2, 3, 4}

for element in myset.difference({3}):
    print(element)
```

If you look at the Python documentation around sets, they are primarily presented from a functional perspective, expecting you to use infix and prefix operators, as well as function. But a `set`, like everything in Python, is just an object and has methods that match most (if not all of) the operators.

If you have an expression like `set1 - set2`, that is a `set` as well, so you can even call methods on it:

```
print(({1, 2, 3} - {3, 4, 5}).union({9}))
```

User @chepner correctly points out in the comments that the method gives you the option of providing other types than just `set`s as a parameter, for example a `tuple`:

```
myset = {1, 2, 3, 4}

for element in myset.difference((3,)):
    print(element)
```

This may perform slightly better, but keep in mind that this won't work:

```
myset = {1, 2, 3, 4}

for element in myset - (3,):
    print(element)
```

And although the call to `.difference()` may be faster with a tuple, you should probably test if `myset - {3}` isn't faster than `myset.difference((3,))` if speed really matters for your code. Especially because what you're really trying to do probably isn't as trivial.

Comment: `difference` can also take an arbitrary iterable, which means you can pass the ever-so-slightly faster to create `(3,)` as the argument :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

```
for element in filter(lambda x: x != element_to_ignore, element_list):
  do_stuff()
```

Comment: After seeing other answers, I'd go with the set difference for this case.